# How to set pseudo selector on hover with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components, pseudo-element

Using **styled-components** in **React**, I wonder how to set ***pseudo selectors*** like :before or :after when hovering an element.
This is css example:

[image]

So how to translate the css code in red rectangle with styled-components?

Answer (score 1):

If the styled component is the same as the target element. You can do the following:

```js
const Link = styled.a`
  &:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
```

If you are targeting an element nested inside the styled component:

```
const LinksWrapper = styled.div`
  a:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
```